# How to Extract text from Toast in android for validation?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-toast

I am using espresso for ui testing of an android app. It has feature of logging in. While logging in, if user enters wrong username or password, a toast appears saying "Incorrect username or password". I want that text for validation. I am writing the tests in android test folder.

I am new to android app testing. Need help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the text/message of a Toast using Espresso testing framework, you can use **onView()** method to check the Toast message view and then try the **withText()** method to obtain the text of the corresponding view.

Hope this was helpful for you!